How to protect electrical cables?
What are my options to protect romex from nails or screws?
I have used the nail on plates on studs where the wire is pulled.  Those are pretty heavy duty and seem pretty solid.
In situations where a wall is not framed, would a rigid metal conduit be sufficient?  If going that route, I understand that it is common practice to terminate the romex in a junction box, then from there pull the individual wires through the conduit rather than the sheathed cable even if it is not strictly forbidden by my local municipality.  Can EMT be used to protect the cable from damage?  Can EMT be covered with drywall?

What type of wall is "not framed"? Do you mean "not finished", as in not covered with drywall? Romex is not to be left exposed if there is no wall covering.

I imagine that not framed, you mean a brick/cement block wall.  Drywall does not bend well, so you would need some type of stud/wood to hold the drywall flat over the EMT.  Using cable in conduit while it can be done, is not fun, so is not recommended as first choice.  Chicago and a couple of other places only allow conduit in the walls.

To be clear, you pull individual surface-marked THHN/THWN/etc. wires in conduit. You do NOT strip NM/B (Romex™) and run those unmarked wires in conduit.

Yes, I have a brick wall that I am contemplating applying rigid foam directly over followed by drywall.  @Ecnerwal, correct.  For it to work, I would allow a channel for the EMT, then drywall.  I am contemplating using spray foam around the EMT to provide some insulation.  I thought EMT can be run in walls, but the non-metallic one cannot.  I also thought that EMT cannot be run through cinder block walls.

You are incorrect about ENT and walls. EMT is fine, but far from the only option that's fine. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/301223/18078

Ok, but ENT wouldn't provide nail protection.

@JohnDoe how do you plan to keep the rigid foam in place, and how to you plan to keep the drywall in place?

For the rigid foam, I might use polyurethane adhesive.  For the drywall, I will use tapcons carefully.  Since the upper portion of the wall is framed in, I would have about 1/2 of the drywall and foam supported as it would be normally and the lower half secured with tapcons.  It will be shimmed off the floor while I'm putting it in, so it should be supported ok.  If it were entirely tapcons, then I'd be worried about driving them through while trying to hold the drywall in place.
